# How to use stata svy etregress postestimation assumption check

Tags: linear-regression, stata, survey, goodness-of-fit

When using survey data and etregress with an endogenous treatment effect in Stata number of diagnostics and post estimate parts stop being available for the use.

```
svy: etregress logwage i.race gender, treat(training = i.education gender) 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                 |             Linearized
                                 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
---------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
logwage                          |
                            race |
                African American |   .3891554   .0031105    12.20   0.000     .2000000    .8474752
                 Asian American  |   .1487310   .0002843    04.11   0.000     .027113     .8765290
                                 |
                          gender |
                         female  |  -.0230411    .010445    -6.85   0.000    -.115341   -.0107295
                                 |


                      1.training |   .3703371   .0451778    10.61   0.000     .2018037    .4186134
  

  ---------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    training                         |
                         i.education |
                         Highschool  |  -.0715731   .0490565     1.28   0.098    -.1106579    .1291781
                            College  |   .1271380   .0401052     3.95   0.003     .0329516    .2107563
                        Grad School  |   .8522143   .0085337     8.99   0.000     .8271381    .9573284
                                     |
                              gender |
                             female  |   .0127444   .0100058     5.33   0.041     .0100558    .0866312
                               _cons |  -1.260083   .0327235   -26.12   0.000    -1.531405   -1.098524
    ---------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------


                             /athrho |   .0051552    .031410     0.17   0.827    -.0722533    .0810246
                            /lnsigma |  -1.872551   .0166818   -73.50   0.000    -1.928624   -1.278064
    ---------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
                                 rho |   .0084120   .0421116                     -.0649947    .0888529
                               sigma |   .4000831   .0038170                      .1925127    .5067780
                              lambda |   .0012673   .0226365                     -.0324029
```

When I have this model simple assumptions related to a linear model like: Check linearity or assumption of independence and the homoscedasticity, normality, or goodness of fit diagnostics do not give output.

A residuals versus predicted values plot could have been a `rvfplot` but this gives the error:

> last estimates not found

Trying `estat gof`gives

> invalid subcommand gof

and the same for the `estat hettest`

```
help etregress postestimation
```

does not discuss model assumption tests or goodness of fit tests which we normally see with regress or log-linear model in Stata.

When I try the `predict residual` or `predict rstudent` nothing is reported making plotting not possible again.

I can provide reproducible example of the problem with the reference given by others:

```
webuse nhanes2f, clear
qui svyset psuid [pweight=finalwgt], strata(stratid)
qui svy: etregress loglead i.female i.diabetes, treat(diabetes = weight age height i.female) // coefl
nlcom pct_eff:(100*(exp(_b[loglead:1.female])-1))
```

Here also the etregress is used with a log transformed dependent variable and a treatment component. Following this model like asked above, how do we check the assumptions and goodness of fit?

Comment: I think you asked this on CV. I've not used this command but as flagged there whatever is immediately available is documented under `help etregress postestimation` and what is not allowed is not documented. But for example there is an easy road from using `predict` to get fitted values, getting residuals by subtraction, and then getting a residual versus fitted plot.

Comment: Conversely, it's entirely plausible to me that no-one has worked out the theory of various diagnostic tests for `etregress` under `svy:`, which is typically why StataCorp do not provide functionality.

Comment: You check the assumptions by following whatever tools the statistical literature has developed. If these exist and are not implemented in Stata, you must implement them manually, which is not going to be a trivial task. What do you expect from people on here to tell you?

Comment: @iPlexpen I did not downvote your question but what you are essentially asking is for someone who has in-depth statistical insight on the matter (unlikely on here) to basically undertake a huge, free coding project for you. The point of my comment is that this is an unrealistic expectation.

Comment: This point has also already been explained to you in [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62823159/) of yours.